# CSS calc() using width and position of element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table, where I would like to move element `div` (last div) to the right.

```
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>...</th>
    <th>...</th>
    ...
    <th>
     <div>
      <span></span>
       <span>
        <div>Move me!</div>
       </span>
     </div>
    </th>
   <tr>
  <thead>
```

The div has following CSS and it's important, that I can't change `postion` to `relative`

```
 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: max-content;
}
```

I would like to add property `left` like this:

```
  left: calc(100% -(position+width)),
```

where `postion` is currently x-coord of div and `width` is the width of the div.

How could I access this values?

PS. Currently my div is placed in such way, that it crosses the border of main div and it leads to appearing of scrollbar. I would like to avoid this by moving `div` to left with negative value (for example if I assign

```
left: -20px;
```

it is moving to the right and I achieve whta I want, but I can't assign it to certain value, because the width of div always changes, ,so it should be dynamically calculated)

What could be possible soultion with Javascript? How could I extract the postion? Right now offsetLeft is 0...

Comment: I am not sure but i think you cannot refer to `position+width` like this

Comment: You must use JavaScript for it

Comment: You can't refer to position and width this way - `calc()` only works with CSS units. See the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc.

Comment: You can neither get the offset position nor the calculated size of an object in CSS, you'll need to use JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 5):

What about `right: 0;` It should stay in your main div while positioning itself on the right side of it (0 pixels from the right side).

Can you post a codepen with an example so we might help you better :)